# Sort array based on second array order

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an array from a plist and each value contains an key and a string and a secondary array that I get from a json file online. I want to order the secondary array based on the keys in the first array.

I want to achieve something like this:

array1:
Item0 - EUR
      - String
Item1 - USD
      - String
Item2 - AUD
      - String
etc

array2:
Item0 - AUD
      - 123.242
Item1 - EUR
      - 535.123
Item2 - USD 
      - 325.646
etc

I have the same key index on both but I want to get the value for the key index from array2 based on the order of the key index in array1.

I have researched online but I cannot find a suitable solution that I can understand how to implement it.

How can I implement this?

Here is the plist file - https://gist.github.com/iulianvarzaru/11c400ba1edf4a165082

And the json file - https://gist.github.com/iulianvarzaru/1915e02a9201c57f49b3

Comment: what is the key, what the value?

Comment: The key AUD, EUR, USD etc ( these valus I get from Json file) and evey key has asigned a value. Now I have created a plist file to re-ordered this keys in different way. I want to reorder the json array to retrieve the value for each key.

Comment: Do you really care about the order of array1 or are you just trying to get the description from the currency code?

Comment: Yes, I need the order to be in that specific way because the order in the json file its not always the same.

Comment: The JSON file does not contain an array, it contains a dictionary which has no order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the JSON file you've linked to doesn't contain an array but a dictionary, you can simply iterate over `array1` from the plist file. Each element of that array is a dictionary with a "Cod" key and a "Descriere" key. Get the value for the "Cod" key and then simply use that value as the key into the dictionary from the JSON file.

```
NSDictionary* jsonFileDict = ...;
NSDictionary* jsonFileInnerDict = jsonFileDict[@"rate"];
for (NSDictionary* dict in array1)
{
    NSString* code = dict[@"Cod"];
    NSNumber* jsonNumber = jsonFileInnerDict[code];
    // Do something with jsonNumber
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like these are key-value pairs, in which case, you can convert it to a Map, and then do direct lookups.

If you can manipulate the JSON file as JSON, then it reduces a conversion, but may not be the most efficient implementation.

Caveats:

1. This method assumes that you wont have key overloading (which is possible in a numeric array, but not in a map)
2. This requires a conversion from one data structure to another

EDIT: (due to increased information by OP).

The JSON file you receive doesn't contain an array, it contains an object. Thus, all the values are  direct-lookup. So, you can traverse your array in Obj-c, and directly access the corresponding values in the JSON.

Sorry about the lack of actual code-samples.

Comment: are you talking about objective-c?

Comment: The concept is language agnostic. It would be best implemented in Obj-c with a `NSMutableDictionary`

Comment: the question is about objective-c. cocoa has no map, numeric array or key overloading. the is question targets on the real API.

Comment: `The JSON file you receive doesn't contain an array, it contains an object.` An array is an object too. it contains a dictionary. and not all objects have direct look up.

Comment: oops, silly me. Anyway, your answer should be the accepted answer. It does what I was trying to explain, but with code examples.

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with a dictionary in the response, not an array.

You should transform it to something like

```
{ 
    @"currency": @"EUR",
    @"value": 123.45
}
```

create and sort it it like

```
NSArray *keys = @[@"EUR",@"USD",@"AUD"];
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"AUD":@(123.242), @"EUR": @(535.123), @"USD": @(325.646)};
NSMutableArray *result = [@[] mutableCopy];

for (NSString *key in keys) {
    [result addObject:@{@"value":dict[key], @"currency": key}];
}
NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

---

```
(
        {
        currency = EUR;
        value = "535.123";
    },
        {
        currency = USD;
        value = "325.646";
    },
        {
        currency = AUD;
        value = "123.242";
    }
)
```

Or write a model class that can handle this information.